# Python 3.10 optional parameter: type union vs None default

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

It's not a huge issue, but as a matter of style, I was wondering about the best way to indicate *optional* function parameters...

Before type hints, it was like this for parameter `b`:

```
def my_func(a, b = None)
```

Before Python 3.10, using type hints:

```
def my_func(a, b: Optional[str])
```

With Python 3.10's lovely pipe-type notation (see [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/)):

```
def my_func(a, b: str | None)
```

The latter seems the obvious choice of the three options, but I was wondering if this completely eliminates the need to specify the *default* `None` value, which would be:

```
def my_func(a, b: str | None = None)
```

EDIT: Thanks to @deceze and @jonrsharpe for pointing out that `def my_func(a, b: str | None)` would still require you to pass a value to `b`: you would explicitly have to pass `None` if you wanted that.

So, the most concise one that will work to ensure that `b` is optional (i.e. the caller does *not* have to pass a value at all) is:

```
def my_func(a, b: str = None)
```

Stylistically, incorporating explicit typing, is `def my_func(a, b: str | None = None)`, i.e. explicit optional typing *plus* default `None` value, ever an option?

Comment: The type hint doesn't replace the default value. With just `b: Optional[str]` you actually still need to pass a value for `b` when calling the function.

Comment: In `def my_func(a, b: Optional[str])` `b` is **not** optional (but you _can_ explicitly pass `None`)!

Comment: Yeah, I just tested this after I wrote the post (face palm!). Semantically, I think it's a bit of hole in Python's typing system: typing a parameter as optional (using old or new pipe style) should really default the value to None.

Comment: Corrected with EDIT above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [PEP-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/):

> A past version of this PEP allowed type checkers to assume an optional type when the default value is None, as in this code:
>
> `def handle_employee(e: Employee = None): ...`
>
> This is no longer the recommended behavior. Type checkers should move towards requiring the optional type to be made explicit.

So the official answer is no. You should specify `... | None = None` for optional arguments.

Comment: This refers to leaving out the None _type_, not the None _value_. You could never leave out the value (that changes the actual runtime behaviour, which type hints don't do).

Comment: @jon yup, it's the answer to the edited question but basically answers both at the same time.